# How to open camera , or call startActivityForResult from a button in recycleriew item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-camera, android-viewholder

I am trying to open the **camera** while clicking on the button Photo , but this button is in an `adapter` of a `recyclerview` , and I couldn't call `startActivityForResult` , is there any way to do it ? or something else to start the **camera** and take pictures as the same way , please explain me how to handle that and why I couldn't call `startActivityForResult` , I saw previous answer and I didn't got it well , here is my code ,

thank you.

```
class DommageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView dommage,componant,side;
Button act_photo;

public DommageViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    dommage=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dommage_value);
    componant=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.componant_value);
    side=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.side_value);
    act_photo = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_photo_dommage);

    act_photo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void bind(DommageGlobale myObject) {
    dommage.setText(myObject.getDammage());
    componant.setText(myObject.getComponant());
    side.setText(myObject.getSide());

}

public interface OnCameraButtoClick{
    void onClick();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == act_photo.getId()){

    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

Call following method inside your `if(view.getId() == act_photo.getId()){ HERE }`

```
public void OpenCamera(){
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

don't forget to add permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Additionally for Marshmallow onwards you need to handle Runtime permission.
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below code;

```
 holder.upload_doc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             taskDiscussionId=   mDataset.get(position).getTaskdiscussId();
                uploadImage();
            }
        });
```

and `uploadImage()` define like this;

```
private void uploadImage() {

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("*/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}
```

Now you can define `startActivityForResult` ...